# "duplicate symbols for architecture" error when subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want `SearchCategoryChooserViewController` to be a subclass of `SearchViewController`, and have set it up like so:

SearchCategoryChooserViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface SearchCategoryChooserViewController : SearchViewController

@end
```

SearchViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Parse/PFCloud.h>
#import "CriteriaViewController.h"



@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButtonOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *topCategory1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *topCategory2;

@end
```

When I try to run the app however, it gives me the following error:

```
    Ld /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.app/Parse+Storyboard normal i386
    cd /Users/Andrew/OneDrive/Dev/Parse---Storyboard
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Andrew/OneDrive/Dev/Parse---Storyboard -filelist /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/Parse+Storyboard.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AdSupport -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -lsqlite3 -framework Parse -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/Parse+Storyboard_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.app/Parse+Storyboard

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SearchViewController._nextButtonOutlet in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SearchViewController._topCategory1 in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SearchViewController._topCategory2 in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SearchViewController._itemSearch in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SearchViewController._nextButton in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchViewController.o
    /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parse+Storyboard-erplilyduxqrboclmgotnylnvcux/Build/Intermediates/Parse+Storyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse+Storyboard.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchCategoryChooserViewController.o
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting those duplicate symbol errors because the code you've provided looks fine, but those two weak NSString properties will always be nil unless you specify them as strong. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usually happens when you #import the `.m` file into your project by mistake instead of importing the header (.h). Make sure you #import only the headers.

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't stay up coding so late :-)

Comment: Thanks. its mistake accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Did you moved the `SearchViewController`, `SearchCategoryChooserViewController` files in project to another place and import to project again ? Make sure delete the previous files.